# Redis sentinel - How to take a server out of loop?

Tags: linux, redis, redis-sentinel, redis-server

I had following deployment of sentinel - 3 redis instances on different servers, 3 sentinels on each of these servers.

Now, I realized that the current master does not have much memory, so I stopped sentinel and redis instance on this particular server. And did the same setup on a new machine. SO, still I have the same deployment, 3 redis instances and 3 sentinels.

The issue is that, now sentinels are saying, master is down, as they think the master is the server which I removed. What should I do to tell sentinel that it need not include that server in loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs about Redis Sentinel, under the chapter [Adding or removing Sentinels](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel#adding-or-removing-sentinels):

> Removing a Sentinel is a bit more complex: Sentinels never forget already seen Sentinels, even if they are not reachable for a long time, since we don't want to dynamically change the majority needed to authorize a failover and the creation of a new configuration number. So in order to remove a Sentinel the following steps should be performed in absence of network partitions:
>
> 1. Stop the Sentinel process of the Sentinel you want to remove.
> 2. Send a `SENTINEL RESET *` command to all the other Sentinel instances (instead of * you can use the exact master name if you want to reset just a single master). One after the other, waiting at least 30 seconds between instances.
> 3. Check that all the Sentinels agree about the number of Sentinels currently active, by inspecting the output of `SENTINEL MASTER mastername` of every Sentinel.

Further:

> ### Removing the old master or unreachable slaves.
>
> Sentinels never forget about slaves of a given master, even when they are unreachable for a long time. This is useful, because Sentinels should be able to correctly reconfigure a returning slave after a network partition or a failure event.
>
> Moreover, after a failover, the failed over master is virtually added as a slave of the new master, this way it will be reconfigured to replicate with the new master as soon as it will be available again.
>
> However sometimes you want to remove a slave (that may be the old master) forever from the list of slaves monitored by Sentinels.
>
> In order to do this, you need to send a `SENTINEL RESET mastername` command to all the Sentinels: they'll refresh the list of slaves within the next 10 seconds, only adding the ones listed as correctly replicating from the current master `INFO` output.